# How to use Google map.data.loadGeoJson with a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, servlets

I need to load multiple sequential data layers on my Google map.
I use a servlet to generate the `GeoJSON` string, which is retrieved by a `XMLHttpRequest`. Then I want to load it using `map.data.loadGeoJson`, but it expects a file as a parameter.
I feel that writing the `GeoJSON` file on the server and then giving the URL as parameter is not efficient.

Is there a way to trick `loadGeoJson` so it accepts the `JSON` string from the servlet ? For example, something like :

```
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","/hello/MyHello?date="+ d.toISOString(),true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
        {
            var geoJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            map.data.loadGeoJson(geoJSON );
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use loadGeoJson for JSON data, use addGeoJson.  `loadGeoJson` is for "remote" data, if you already have the data, use `addGeoJson`.

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","/hello/MyHello?date="+ d.toISOString(),true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
    {
        var geoJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        map.data.addGeoJson(geoJSON );
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks ! it now works. Found the complete reference https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference